req.file is empty or undefined
I want to use the useForm along with a validation system to save data using the append() function and send it to MongoDB with a fetch request. However, when I inspect the formData object, the error is "No files uploaded"
ManageRestaurantForm.jsx
import React from 'react'
import { FormProvider, useForm } from 'react-hook-form'


// PAGES
import DetailsSection from './DetailsSection'
import CuisinesSection from './CuisinesSection'
import MenuSection from './MenuSection'
import ImageSection from './ImageSection'
import { forumFill } from '../../fetch/Fetch'


const ManageRestaurantForm = () => {

  const formMethods = useForm(); 
    const { handleSubmit } = formMethods; 

    
    const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async (formDataJson) => {
      try {
          
          const formData = new FormData();

          formData.append("restaurantName", formDataJson.restaurantName);
          formData.append("city", formDataJson.city);
          formData.append("country", formDataJson.country);
      
          formData.append(
            "deliveryPrice",
            (formDataJson.deliveryPrice * 100).toString());

          formData.append(
            "estimatedDeliveryTime",
            formDataJson.estimatedDeliveryTime.toString());
          
          formData.append("cuisines", formDataJson.cuisines)

          formDataJson.menuItems.forEach((menuItem, index) => {
            formData.append(`menuItems[${index}][name]`, menuItem.name);
            formData.append(
              `menuItems[${index}][price]`,
              (menuItem.price * 100).toString()
            );
          });

        console.log(formDataJson.menuItems)
       formDataJson.menuItems.forEach((menuItem, index) => {
        formData.append(`menuItems[${index}][name]`, menuItem.name);
        formData.append(
          `menuItems[${index}][price]`,
          (menuItem.price * 100).toString()
        );
      });

      if (formDataJson.imageFiles && formDataJson.imageFiles.length > 0) {
        Array.from(formDataJson.imageFiles).forEach((file, index) => {
          formData.append(`imageFiles[${index}]`, file);
        });
      }
      
      console.log(formData)
        await forumFill("http://localhost:7000/api/my/restaurant", formData);

        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
          
        }
    })


  return (
    <div>
      <FormProvider {...formMethods}>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>

            {/* FORM COMPONENTS */}

          <DetailsSection />
          <CuisinesSection/>
          <MenuSection />
          <ImageSection />


            <span className='flex justify-end'>
                      <button type="submit" className='bg-red-600  text-white h-full mb-10 w-40 rounded hover:rounded-md hover:duration-300 duration-300 p-2 font-bold hover:bg-red-500 cursor-pointer text-2xl'>
                          Save
                     </button>
            </span>
            </form>
      </FormProvider>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ManageRestaurantForm

Above, the formFill function is come from:
// forms/manage-restaurant
export const forumFill = async (url, data) => {

    try {
      const formDataJSON = JSON.stringify(data); 
    const rawResponse = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: formDataJSON 
    });
      const content = await rawResponse.json();
  
    console.log(formDataJSON)
    console.log(content);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    } 
  
  };

Backend of this jsx file:
const cloudinary = require("cloudinary").v2;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Restaurant } = require("../mongodb/models/restaurant");

class Controller {
    async createMyRestaurant(req, res) {
        try {

            if (!req.file || req.file.length === 0) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "No files uploaded" });
            }

            const existingRestaurant = await Restaurant.findOne({ user: req.userId });

            if (existingRestaurant) {
                return res.status(409).json({ message: "User restaurant already exists" });
            }

            const imageFile = req.File;
            
            console.log(`Your imageFile is ${imageFile}`)

            const b64 = Buffer.from(imageFile.buffer).toString("base64");
            const dataURI = "data:" + imageFile.mimetype + ";base64," + b64;
            const uploadResponse = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(dataURI);
            const imageUrl = uploadResponse.url;

            console.log(`Your imageUrl is ${imageUrl}`)

            const restaurant = new Restaurant({
                body: req.body,
                lastUpdate: new Date(),
            });

            await restaurant.save();

            res.status(201).send(restaurant);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).json({ message: "Something went wrong :(" });
        }
    }
}

module.exports = Controller;

Project: githubLink
The expected result was, with the help of useForm creating an object appropriately and POST it into my mongoDB table but the error that I face is that "No files uploaded" which is req.file is empty or undefined.

I recommend you use multipart/form-data header to upload the file since  application/json header send the data in json format. If you really want to use application/json, you need to use something like


const file = document.querySelector("input[name=myfile]")
const reader = new FileReader()
const dataURL = FileReader.readAsDataURL(file)
console.log(dataURL)



Btw, You can open the browser dev-tool and navigate to 'network' tab and check the body of your POST request.
